# Problem about reflexive space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Could someone help me with the following problem, I don't know how to do it

Letbe $X$ a reflexive space and $Y$ a closed subespace of $X^*$ such that if   $f(x)=0 \forall{f}\in{Y} $ then $x=0$. Prove that  $X^*=Y$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $x^*\in X^*\setminus Y$. By Hahn-Banach there exists $x^{**}\in X^{**}$ with $x^{**}(x^*)=1$ and $x^{**}(y)=0$ for all $y\in Y$. But $X$ is reflexive...

Comment: Where do you use the contition above Y?

Comment: In the second sentence. Hahn-Banach has hypotheses - if $Y$ is not closed the second sentence is obviously  nonsense.